# Why Is User Automatically Logged out?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic3, angularfire2

I have a simple app set up in Ionic 3 with a login page and a home page. I check to see if the user is logged in, then redirect to either the login page or the home page. That part seems to work.

After the login, on the home page I am trying to get the current logged in user. I get the user twice, and then it returns null twice. Why is the user not persistent? According the the AngularFire docs, the login should be persistent by default.

app.component.ts:

```
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage:any;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
      const authObserver = this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user =>{
        if (user){
          this.rootPage = 'HomePage';
          authObserver.unsubscribe();
        } else {
          this.rootPage = 'LoginPage'
          authObserver.unsubscribe();
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

login.ts:

```
export class LoginPage {

    user = {} as User;

    constructor(public authData: AuthProvider, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
    }

    login(user: User){
        this.authData.loginUser(user.email, user.password).then( authData => {
            this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
        }, error => {
            console.log('Something went wrong')
        });
    }
}
```

home.ts:

```
export class HomePage {

    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public authData: AuthProvider, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
        this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            console.log(user);
        });
    }
}
```

logs:

```
login.ts:27 ionViewDidLoad LoginPage
home.ts:22 Hk {D: Array(0), G: "XIzaSyDn9pRx23NeEaCNVMQ0sBveDxYEsGrGvRA", s: "[DEFAULT]", A: "pigs-n-bulls-xxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com", b: xh, …}
home.ts:22 Hk {D: Array(0), G: "XIzaSyDn9pRx23NeEaCNVMQ0sBveDxYEsGrGvRA", s: "[DEFAULT]", A: "pigs-n-bulls-xxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com", b: xh, …}
home.ts:27 ionViewDidLoad HomePage
home.ts:22 null
home.ts:22 null
```

Comment: Have you tried removing this line: `authObserver.unsubscribe()`

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.afAuth.auth.auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);`

or

`this.afAuth.auth.auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);`

Then in your auth check code:

`this.afAuth.auth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (!user) {
}
}`

Take not I am using Angularfire, but accessing the Firebase auth functions directly.

Comment: Tried this and it still does not persist the login

Comment: Have you checked the application tab in Chrome Developers Tools. Should be able to find your firebase auth details if its working correctly.